# xlsread and waitbar MATLAB

Tags: matlab, progress-bar, xls

I have installed Matlab r2010a in my computer.

How to show updated progress in a waitbar  figure while data is reading in parallel using xlsread function from matlab?

Thanks a lot for answering.

(EDIT)

what I mean is that while **xlsread** is loading the data one by one you can see the loading progress in **waitbar**.

Is there any way?

PD: I just want to load data from one *.xls file

Comment: What do you mean by "in parallel"? AFAIK, `xlsread` is not inherently parallelized. In any case, I don't think there is a way to do this, since you'd have to modify xlsread directly to show progress.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options:

1. A difficult option: create a `.mex` file and work out different MATLAB versions' undocumented memory representations (probably quite difficult, but I believe it's possible with some debugger).
2. An easier way to do it: Create your own `myxlsread.m` using `xlsread.m`, `xlsreadCOM.m` and `xlsreadXLSX.m` as a point of departure.`
3. If all you need is to update `waitbar` in a loop between consecutive `xlsread` commands, that's very easy.

`1.` The `.mex` file solution:
If you want to show the progress of a single `xlsread` function call, I believe things get quite complicated. First, you would need to have two threads, and for that you would need to use `.mex` files or some other means. The second matter is that AFAIK `xlsread` doesn't send out any signals of its progress, which means that your `.mex` function would need to somehow get the memory addresses of the variables (cell arrays or matrices etc.) of the called `xlsread` function. If this is what you want, then this document would probably be useful: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlabs-internal-memory-representation/ Do note that MATLAB's internal memory representation is completely undocumented and may change whenever and it's different in different MATLAB versions, so for a single `waitbar` this would be too much work.

`2.` The `myxlsread.m` solution:
The good news is that `xlsread` is not a built-in (at least not in MATLAB R2012a) so you can read the code and trace it with MATLAB debugger without problems. As it's not a built-in what would be a possible option is creating your own custom `myxlsread.m`, by taking `xlsread.m`, `xlsreadCOM.m` and `xlsreadXLSX.m` as an example or by directly modifying them to add `waitbar` update function calls, if in your situation copyright problems are not an issue (eg. you don't distribute the code or local laws permit it). I think modifying or recreating your `myxlsread.m` is the most viable way to do it.

`3.` The `xlsread` in a loop solution:
However, if all you want is to update `waitbar` between separate `xlsread` function calls, then that's not an issue at all, it would be something like:

```
XlsFilenamesCellArray = { 'file1.xls', 'file2.xls', 'file3.xls' };
NumberOfFiles = size(XlsFilenamesCellArray, 2)

h = waitbar(0, '1', 'Name', 'xlsread loop progress', 'CreateCancelBtn', 'setappdata(gcbf,     ''canceling'', 1)');

for Index = 1:size(XlsFilenamesCellArray, 2)
    waitbar(Index/NumberOfFiles, h, sprintf('reading .xls file %d of %d', Index, NumberOfFiles));
    [num{Index}, text{Index}, raw{Index}] = xlsread(XlsFilenamesCellArray{Index});
end
```

Comment: Hi @nrz It's me again. Would you mind tell me what I should do to get an updated variable inside `xlsread.m` step-by-step when is loading the data? 
Thanks a lot